# Lorentz indices to label rotation irreducible representations

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, spinors

Consider the $A_\mu\in\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$, the vector representation of the restricted Lorentz group. One can decompose this vector under spatial rotations as $A_\mu\in 0\oplus 1$ where $A_0$ transforms as a 3D scalar and $A_i$ transforms as a 3D vector. If say we had $\psi_a\in\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right)\oplus\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ a Dirac spinor, under rotations it transforms as $\psi_a=\frac{1}{2}_L\oplus\frac{1}{2}_R$ where $a=1,2$ will be the left part and $a=3,4$ will be the right part.

The question I have is when we consider higher representations, say a $\frac{3}{2}$ particle, $\psi_{\mu a}\in\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)\otimes\left[\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right)\oplus\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]$. It is prety clear that under rotations it transforms as $\psi_{\mu a}\in\left(\frac{1}{2}\oplus\frac{1}{2}\oplus\frac{3}{2}\right)_L\oplus\left(\frac{1}{2}\oplus\frac{1}{2}\oplus\frac{3}{2}\right)_R$. However I don't see how I can distribute the indices $\mu$ and $a$ under rotations.

I am also interested in the general concept.

$\textbf{Edit: (to give more details for what my question is)}$

If we take the scalar part of the $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)=0\oplus1$, and multiply it by the the Dirac spinor we get $\frac{1}{2}_L\oplus\frac{1}{2}_R$. So I would say the part $\psi_{0a}$ transforms as $\frac{1}{2}_L\oplus\frac{1}{2}_R$.

What's left is $\psi_{ia}$ which transforms as $\left(\frac{1}{2}\oplus\frac{3}{2}\right)_L\oplus\left(\frac{1}{2}\oplus\frac{3}{2}\right)_R$. My question is: What part of the indices $i,a$ transforms as $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_L\oplus\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_R$?

Comment: I do not think the last formula is OK. First, compute the tensor product in $SL(2,\mathbb C) $ correctly, IIRC, this reduction theory from $SL(2,\mathbb C) $ to $SU(2) $ is explained in the group theory book by Willard Miller.

Comment: @DanielC $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$ decomposes as $0\oplus 1$. Multiplying this with the left component of the Dirac spinor, you get  $(0\oplus 1)\otimes \frac{1}{2}_L = \left(\frac{1}{2}\oplus\left(\frac{1}{2}\oplus\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)_L$. You can do the same for the right component.

Comment: OK, I see. The $SU(2)$ index structure can be assigned only by correctly computing the dimensions of the vector spaces. Try to find Miller's book.

Comment: I am not pretty sure where exactly you point to in Miller's book. (I am not familiar with the book)

Comment: I do not have it in front of me, but as far as I recall, it is the only book discussion the reduction of SL(2,C) representations under the SU(2) subgroup.

Comment: @Pinkman98 write down how the Lorentz group acts on an object of your choice and then consider rotations as part of the Lorentz (take a matrix $\Lambda$ that corresponds to rotations).

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Finite-dimensional_representations) 3.2.5. Your gravitino is throroughgoingly unsound. The Lorentz rep is (3/2,0)⊕ (0,3/2) gotten from (1,1/2)⊕(1/2,1). See Weinberg's The QTF, footnote p 232.

Comment: @CosmasZachos say we have a $V\in (3/2,0)\oplus(0,3/2)$ which is gotten from $\psi_{\mu a}\in(1/2,1/2)\otimes[(1/2,0)\oplus(0,1/2)]$. Is there a way to restrict the indices $\mu, a$ to the $(3/2,0)\oplus(0,3/2)$? what are the lorentz indices of $V$?

Comment: I am still looking for an answer :) thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27552/why-arent-the-spin-3-2-fields-in-the-3-2-00-3-2-representation) is a close duplicate.

$\psi_{\mu~\alpha}$, in $$\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)\otimes\left[\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right)\oplus\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\right],$$ has 16 components; so you project out the spinor piece, $\gamma\cdot \psi_\alpha =0$, $  \left[\left(\frac{1}{2},0\right)\oplus\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]$,which removes 4 components,
leaving you with 12:
$$
 \left[\left({1},\frac{1}{2}\right)\oplus\left(\frac{1}{2},{1} \right)\right].
$$

However, 4 of these remaining components are gauge (local susy) degrees of freedom, $\partial_\mu \epsilon_\alpha$, that do not enter the R-S action, so they are projected out as in vector gauge theories, leaving you with just 8,
$$ \left[\left(\frac{3}{2},0\right)\oplus\left(0,\frac{3}{2}\right)\right],$$
a left-handed and a right-handed quartet.

NB   On-shell, one may go on: the absence of $\partial_0 \psi_{0~\alpha}$ from the action allows fixing $\psi_0=0$, reducing the 8 components to 4, and the Majorana condition reduces them to only 2 d.o.f., the extreme polarization states, analogous to photons, explained in [Freedman & van Proeyen](http://www.nucleares.unam.mx/%7Ealberto/apuntes/freedman.pdf).